# actix web lifetime in web::Data

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am trying to work with Data in acitx web, but it wont work with a defined lifetime. Why am i getting this error and how do i fix it? `implicit elided lifetime not allowed here assuming a 'static lifetime`

```rs
#[get("/search/{query}/")]
async fn testing(search: Path<SearchIdentifier>,test: Data< Test >) -> Json<String> {...}
```

```
error[E0726]: implicit elided lifetime not allowed here
  --> src/api/file.rs:86:62
   |
86 | async fn testing(search: Path<SearchIdentifier>,test: Data< Test >) -> Json<String> {
   |                                                            ^^^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>`
   |
   = note: assuming a `'static` lifetime...
```

```rs
pub struct Test<'a> {
    test: Test<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Test<'a> {
    pub fn new(conn: MysqlConnection) -> Self {
        let test = Test { conn: &conn };
        Self {test}
    }
```

Comment: Please always post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: This code is not a valid Rust code: `-> {}`. And it will not compiler regardless, because returning something containing a reference to the parameter `connect` is not going to work.

Comment: i added the full error `cargo check`. Thats a small mistake i made while simplifying the code for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test` contains a lifetime - `'a`. You omitted it. Usually, when you do that, the compiler uses the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) to figure out what the lifetime should be - in this case, for example, it would become:

```rust
fn testing<'a>(search: Path<SearchIdentifier>,test: Data<Test<'a>>) -> Json<String>
```

However, this is not a normal function. This is an `async` function. And `async` functions are not allowed to *implicitly* elide the lifetime - they have to *explicitly* elide it using `'_`, that is:

```rust
async fn testing(search: Path<SearchIdentifier>,test: Data<Test<'_>>) -> Json<String>
```

Or, of course, the fully-specified version with `'a`.

The reason for that is that implicit lifetime elision on structs is considered a design mistake, because it does not allow you to reason easily about the lifetimes present in your function. In fact, I recommend putting at the crate root the following:

```rust
#![forbid(rust_2018_idioms)]
```

To (among other things) disallow that for *any* function, not just `async`.